# How to combine multiple rows from 4 tables into one single row in a new table in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, join, sql-server-2012

Hello everyone my name is Penelope and I have about 4 years of SQL experience.  First off I would like to thank you guys for taking the time to read this and then provide a direction, example, walk though, or guidance.
I have a SQL issue/puzzle that I just cant figure out.I have tried unsuccessfully to concatenate several records into on record.  I have some experience with Joins but this one seems to be a little over my head and I was hoping for a little help or guidance.  I want just one long student record but as you will see I am getting the right data but multiple records are being created because some tables have more than one record.  Below you can see the names of the tables and columns that I need to insert as one record into a table called EntireStudentI . My SQL, and my current results 
I have table called TP which gives me basic info about the student in one record

```
trans_type
trk_link
service_db     
scn
given_nm
surname_nm
cc
sex
grade
dob
marital_st
pob_city
pob_cntry
UScitizenship_CD
```

I have a table called P which will give me one record where I want the passport number

```
pass_nbr
```

I have a table called VI which could give me multiple records as the student can have multiple visas

pass_nbr – same name as in passport but in this case it is Visa Number so in my SQL I set it as VisaNo in order to be less confusing. This can be no records, one, two…

Finally I have a table called PD which are dependent/family members of student.  This can be no records, one, two…

given_nm and surname_nm (these will be concatenated to make DepName)

```
dep_rel
birth-dt
```

What I want to do is have one record which has the columns listed above for TP.

Then add the pass_nbr as a column from the P table.

Then add the VisaNo(s) from the VI table as a comma delimited column -The VisaNo could be blank, or one VisaNo or multiple VisaNo.  Example would be an empty column value, one number ie. 89888 or multiple values 89888,78908,78999.

Finally I would like to add dependent info columns from the PD table.  A student does not need to have dependents or they could have multiple dependents such as a spouse and a child – A spouse and a child would create two records be two separate records in the PD table.  In my single record I would hope to have column delimited Depname, column delimited dep_rel, and comma delimited birth_dt

All these tables are tied together by a column called trk_link which is the key

This is my SQL

```
SELECT t.trans_type
      ,t.trk_link
      ,t.service_db     
      ,t.scn
      ,t.given_nm
      ,t.surname_nm
      ,t.cc
      ,t.sex
      ,t.grade
      ,t.dob
      ,t.marital_st
      ,t.pob_city
      ,t.pob_cntry
      ,CASE t.UScitizenship_CD
          WHEN 'H' THEN 'Holds'
          WHEN 'DNH' THEN 'Does Not Hold'
          else ''
          End as Student_Citizenship_Status

      --,t.UScitizenship_CD
      ,t.trk_link20
      ,p.pass_nbr
      ,v.pass_nbr as VisaNo,
      CONCAT(p2.given_nm, ' ', p2.surname_nm) As DepName
      --,p2.given_nm
      --,p2.surname_nm
      ,p2.dep_rel
      ,p2.birth_dt
      ,CASE p2.UScitizenship_CD
          WHEN 'H' THEN 'Holds'
          else 'Does Not Hold'
          End as Dependent_Citizenship_Status

from TP t
inner join P p
on t.[trk_link] = p.[trk_link]

inner Join VI v

on p.[trk_link] = v.[trk_link]

inner join PD p2
on t.[trk_link] = p2.[trk_link]

where t.trk_link = '22985200458053000003171117104111'
```

And this is the result

[image]

Thanks So Much Guys
Penelope!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of ways to achieve this. You can use `STUFF` and `XML PATH` or you can use a user defined function.

The easiest method would be add user defined function and use it wherever you want.You don't even have to create the function.It's already available at [GROUP_CONCAT string aggregate for SQL Server](https://groupconcat.codeplex.com/).

You can use it as follows:

```
SELECT some_id,
       dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(some_column) AS as delimited_list
FROM dbo.some_table
GROUP BY some_id;
```

It gives an output like:

```
some_id           delimited_list
----------------- -----------------------------------
1                 red,green,blue
2                 cyan,magenta,yellow,key
```

**OR**

You can try using `STUFF` and `XML PATH` as I said before.

```
SELECT t.trans_type
      ,t.trk_link
      ,t.service_db     
      ,t.scn
      ,t.given_nm
      ,t.surname_nm
      ,t.cc
      ,t.sex
      ,t.grade
      ,t.dob
      ,t.marital_st
      ,t.pob_city
      ,t.pob_cntry
      ,CASE t.UScitizenship_CD
          WHEN 'H' THEN 'Holds'
          WHEN 'DNH' THEN 'Does Not Hold'
          else ''
          End as Student_Citizenship_Status

      --,t.UScitizenship_CD
      ,t.trk_link20
      ,p.pass_nbr
      --,v.pass_nbr as VisaNo,
      ,STUFF((SELECT VisaNo  
               from VI as v
               where v.[trk_link]=p.[trk_link] 
               FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as VisaNumbers
      ,CONCAT(p2.given_nm, ' ', p2.surname_nm) As DepName
      --,p2.given_nm
      --,p2.surname_nm
      ,p2.dep_rel
      ,p2.birth_dt
      ,CASE p2.UScitizenship_CD
          WHEN 'H' THEN 'Holds'
          else 'Does Not Hold'
          End as Dependent_Citizenship_Status

from TP t
inner join P p
on t.[trk_link] = p.[trk_link]
--inner Join VI v
--on p.[trk_link] = v.[trk_link]  
inner join PD p2 on t.[trk_link] = p2.[trk_link]
where t.trk_link = '22985200458053000003171117104111'
```

**Note:** In the description it was given that VisNumber is saved as `VisaNo`  in `v` table.But in your query you are trying to select `pass_nbr`. So, I'm not sure how its saved in your db. So do the changes accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Jibin!!.  The second example with a little tweaking gave me exactly what I needed.  Penelope

Comment: @PenelopeEstes I'm glad it worked out for you. You can consider marking this as right answer, so that it will be useful for the other people who refer this question.